# Converting an int to String in C++

Tags: c++, string, arduino, int

I have been working on a project where I need to convert an int8_t variable to a string. I did a bit of reading on this and came to a conclusion that using Strint(int8_t) is an option.

Here is my code:

```
int8_t matt = 0;
matt += 1;
char string[3]=String(matt);
tft.textWrite(string);// this is used to display text on an lcd display (arduino)
```

For some reason the method I used did not work so I researched a bit more and found out String(matt) is actually a String object. I don't really know if this is true for a fact. In order for the tft.textWrite(); to work it should look something like this.

Here is the code:

```
 char string[15]= "Hello, World! ";
 tft.textWrite(string);
```

I tried using this also:

```
char string[3];
sprintf(string, "%ld", matt);
```

However this did not work.

Can anybody help?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with std::to_string(0)?

Comment: I can't use that in arduino

Comment: `char string[3]` should be `char string[5]` as it needs to hold e.g. `-100`, i.e. 4 chars and a termination. Also: What do mean by `However this did not work` ? In which way did it fail?

Comment: You can just convert back to a char array if you want to use the textWrite function, something like char string[1024];
std::strcpy(string, std::to_string(0).c_str());

Comment: Because what happened is it starting printing weird characters for some reason on the screen. If I just say char string[3]="1" everything prints fine.

Comment: The "duplicate" answer does not tag arduino, so you should check the avr-libc itoa(int val, char* target, int radix) solution there. Less overhead than snprintf or String(int val).

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine.

```
sprintf(string, "%ld", matt);
```

%ld is used for long int. you are using int8_t which is of range -128 to +128, it is better to use %d.

Answer (score 0):

This code is nearly right

```
char string[3];
sprintf(string, "%ld", matt);
```

first

```
"%ld"
```

expects a `long int` as a type you need to find one that can print an 8 bit int. I think its "%hh".

second your

```
char string[3];
```

is too short! what if matt is 100 then you use 3 chars but you still need room for the ending zero (and sign). So it should be at least

```
char string[5];
```

third the code

```
sprintf(string, "%ld", matt);
```

is unsafe as it can write beyond the end of string as it would in your original code, use

```
snprintf(string, sizeof(string), "%ld", matt);
```

Comment: As everything with rank less than `int` is promoted to int when passed to variadic function, you need to use `%d` format specifier.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot, that would simplify it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to keep in mind that there is no String type in C, only fixed sized char arrays (type: char* or char[]). We still call them strings, but keep that in mind.

Your attempt with sprintf looked good to me. Are you shure your environment includes the full C Standard Library ? If not, you will have to code your own format function. If yes, have you included string.h ?

Anyway, try to use snprintf() to precise the size of the target, it is safer.

**EDIT:** This post applies to the good ol' C style, which I did not see was off topic

Comment: The question is about C++, not C. C++ definitely has a string type. We don't bully ourselves with character arrays any more.

Comment: Please tell me you didn't believe that X)

Comment: Didn't believe what?

Comment: "we don't bully ourselves with character arrays anymore" Have you heard of low level or embedded development ?

Comment: Heard of it? I do it for a living, mate. None of this is relevant, though: the simple fact is that your answer is geared towards a C developer (or, fine, a C++ developer who is unable to use the C++ standard library because he is programming hardware from the 1980s), which the OP is not.

Comment: In fairness I did just spot the [tag:arduino] tag. If Arduino does not support the C++ standard library and/or heap allocations, please adjust your answer so that it does not talk about "C" but about the limitations of C++ on that platform. Otherwise, what I said above still applies.

Comment: So do I, so tell me how you avoid using it ? Isn't "dynamic" (better say undefined) behavior a capital waste of runtime as well as memory ?

Comment: You seem to be engaging in some sort of holy war over coding style. That's not what answers (or comments!) are for. Please stick to the topic at hand.

Comment: I am genuinely interested in talking with you in fact :D

Answer (score -1):

the following code should work:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  int8_t matt = 0;
  matt += 1;
  char string[1]; 
  sprintf(string, "%ld", matt);
  std::cout << string << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

it prints "1".

Comment: you saw the "arduino" tag? Among others, there's no std::cout ;)